# ubuntu kernel sending task to isolated core

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu

My development machine is ubuntu realtime kernel and I am observing that it's sending some processes and task (for example make, gcc, process related to code build etc) to isolated CPUs. Here are some relavant details:

1. number of CPU: 64 (32 hyprethreaded physical cores)
2. uname -a

> Linux ran1312 5.15.0-1041-realtime #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Tue Jun
> 20 18:34:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

3. cat /proc/cmdline

> BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1041-realtime
> root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--1-ubuntu--lv ro intel_iommu=on iommu=pt
> vfio_pci.enable_sriov=1 vfio_pci.disable_idle_d3=1
> usbcore.autosuspend=-1 selinux=0 enforcing=0 nmi_watchdog=0
> crashkernel=auto softlockup_panic=0 audit=0 cgroup_disable=memory
> mce=off hugepagesz=1G hugepages=60 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=0
> default_hugepagesz=1G kthread_cpus=0,1,32-63 irqaffinity=0,1,32-63
> skew_tick=1 isolcpus=managed_irq,domain,2-31 nohz_full=2-31
> rcu_nocbs=2-31 nosoftlockup

4. We are using tuned-adm for CPU isolation and other performance tuning.

As you can see, I have tried to keep CPU 2-31 as isolated CPU, which will be used by our software stack for CPU affinity. CPU 0,1,32-63 are non-isolated.

However when I give a code build, I see all of the processes and sub-processes spawned by code build are going to CPU id 3. When looked at htop, my CPU id 3 is 100% loaded and other CPUs are barely doing anything. I checked "taskset -cp" for few of the such processes. All seems to have affinity = 0-63.

Note: I had similar /proc/cmdline in older development server, which was CentOS realtime, but I did not see such issues there. The isolcpu argument there did not contain "managed_irq,domain" though.

These two behaviors are un-expected to me:

- Kernel sending anything to isolated cores ?
- Kernel not spreading process or sub-processes spawned by code build to other CPUs and keeping everything in single CPU ? This causes super slowdown of code build.

Question: Assuming I am correct and all of this is not expected behavior, how do I debug this further.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was with the tuned version (2.15) installed in my server. Where as the latest tuned version available with Ubuntu 23.x is 2.20. After upgrading tuned version to 2.20 and after reapplying the realtime profile, the system is behaving as expected.